# Problems with using sessions in MySQL querys

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am trying to use information from a session to query a MySQL database in order to update a user's password.  The code itself looks like it should work from what I can tell, but when I run it, the password field in the database does not change.  Here is the relevant code:

```
<?php 
$accountname = $_SESSION[‘login’];
echo $accountname; //I am using this to make sure the session variable is working properly.  It does echo the text of the variable correctly.
$newpassword = $_POST["newpassword"]; 
$connection = mysqli_connect("I have the right information in here") or die(mysqli_error()); 

$updatepw = "UPDATE Login SET password = '$newpassword' WHERE account = '$accountname'";
mysqli_query($connection, $updatepw);   
echo "<p>Your password has been updated.</p>";
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Can anyone see why this code is not working?

Comment: `$_SESSION[‘login’];` is that supposed to be using the curly quotes? Also, instead of echo'ing `$accountname`, use `var_dump($accountname);`. It will surround the text with quotes and give you more information like `string(4) 'test'` so you know that if it is blank you would see `string(0) ''`. And dump out the password and dump out the query to make sure you are getting what you expect.

Comment: Also, obligatory sql injection warning, don't store un-hashed passwords warning and use prepared queries with bind'ed variables warning.

Comment: Thanks!  After some other tests, I realize the issue was elsewhere.  But that reminder also reminded me that I need to go back and hash all the passwords before I make this live :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are getting the value in :

> $newpassword = $_POST["newpassword"];

Please debug it by using exit after this statement .
Hope this help.